# Can I divide an array or string into multiple variables?

Tags: php, javascript, string, json, arrays

**Here's where I've been:**
I made a PHP client call via soap to retrieve an array of data,
I successfully receieved and converted my array to JSON via json_encode,
I then echoed it back to my page.

**Here's where I am:**
I get back my array in this format...
*{"MethodName":"ID,11|1|Item1,22|2|Item2,33|3|Item3"}*

**Here's where I want to be:**
Using Javascript or JSON, my objective is to end up with 2 variables (Method & ID) and one variable array (ItemList)...ie

- var Method = "MethodName";
- var ID = "ID";
- var ItemList = ['11|1|Item1' , '22|2|Item2' , '33|3|Item3'];

I have the front and back of my script working, but I'm stumped on the array(string)...
**How do I parse, divide, or split this result?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i'd probably try a regex first thing. something like

```
var match = data.match(/\{"(.+)"\:"([^,]+),(.+)"\}/);
```

the parentheses will separate the matches. `match[0]` will be the whole thing, `match[1]` will be the method name, `match[2]` will be the id, `match[3]` will be the remainder as a string. you can then do

```
var itemList = match[3].split(',');
```

to get the array for the 3rd part.

Comment: So simple, it strips away the the extra characters and breaks things up just the way I need it.

Answer (score 5):

You would make this much simpler on yourself if you had it as a mixed array in php before you called json_encode (so that instead of a string, each item would be it's own JSON object).

Example:

```
$arr = array();
$itemList = array();
$itemList[1] = "11|1";
$itemList[2] = "22|2";
$itemList[3] = "33|3";

$arr['Method']="MethodName";
$arr['ID']= "ID";
$arr['itemList'] = $itemList;

$output = json_encode($arr);
```

This results in `$output` having the following JSON:

```
{"Method":"MethodName","ID":"ID","itemList":{"1":"11|1","2":"22|2","3":"33|3"}}
```

Which you can then easily pull out, as the itemList is an array in JSON already.

Comment: This would probably be the best way to go about it. However, after I tried it, it wasn't giving me the results I needed. It would probably serve me better in a different situation. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your intial array is initial_array with value {"MethodName":"ID,11|1|Item1,22|2|Item2,33|3|Item3"}

```
for (key in initial_array) {  
  Method = key;                     // Method = "MethodName"
  break;
}
myvalue = initial_array[Method];
myarray = myvalue.split(",");      // myarray = ["ID","11|1|Item1",...]
ID = myarray[0];                   // ID = "ID"
ItemList = myarray.splice(1);      // ItemList = ["11|1|Item1","22|2|Item2",...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
var myobject = {"MethodName":"ID,11|1|Item1,22|2|Item2,33|3|Item3"};
var itemlist = [];
var method;
var ID;

for (key in myobject) { 
    method = key;
    break;
}

itemlist = myobject[method].split(',');
ID = itemlist.shift();
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KETBn/) for you to run.